# convert and display image in C

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I'm going to put a background on my embedded console application.
The question is simple: I just don't know how to do that :)
suppose I have a picture of any format and want to convert it to character array to print it.
As i told you I'm clueless on this one, so if this is a bad approach, please let me know. If any better solution, please suggest it. thank you all!

Comment: You mean something like [AAlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAlib)?

Comment: So, are you using the console?  Gnome?  Tell us more.

Comment: I guess AAlib is my solution(tanx to  Ilmari Karonen). yes, it is a Console not Gnome. no need of animations. I am working on it right now. I found only one sample in its introduction which can't be compiled. What I need now to speed up is a source of sample codes. can u help me with any source I can refer to? tanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide if you want an actual image as is, or if you want an image converted to text:
[image]

If an image converted to text is what you want, have a look at [AAlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAlib) as @IlmariKaronen suggested, or maybe [jp2a](http://csl.sublevel3.org/jp2a/).

If you do want a "real" image, then you need to use a terminal emulator which supports changing background image via a proprietary escape sequence, and I think for instance [eterm supports this](http://www.eterm.org/docs/view.php?doc=ref#std). Then the background could look something like this:
[image]

If you are using the Linux console without X11, there are other options related to FBDEV and bootsplash, but I don't know those as well.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. In guess I just need the simplest form of its functionality: input a simple image and get the rendered picture for printing on my console screen. As I mentioned above, i need some source where i can get some sample code. Any Ideas please? tanx